# Laptop battery quickly losing capacity

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I have a brand new Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 (about two months old). The battery health report in the Lenovo Vantage app shows the current battery capacity as 58.24 Wh, compared to a design capacity of 60.7 Wh. I checked it the day I bought the machine, and the current capacity was 60.7 Wh too at the time. The current cycle count is 15.

Laptop has been plugged in almost 24x7 with conservation mode enabled, so battery is always at 60%. These batteries are supposed to lose ~5% capacity over a year, not 4% in a quarter of that time. I'm hoping to find whatever is causing this and fix it before it gets serious.

The first time I noticed this was when I left the laptop on sleep overnight on battery. The laptop was very hot to touch and the battery had gone to 0% (Modern Standy bug on Windows). When I turned it back on, battery capacity was at 59.8 Wh.

This morning, I had 58.58 Wh. To test if it was sleep mode causing the problem I disabled sleep and left the computer on, plugged in with conservation mode enabled. I checked about 10 hours later to see capacity at 58.24.

Any suggestions on how to preserve the battery? Am I wrong to leave it on Conservation mode throughout the day?

One last thing I've noticed (this might just be my imagination) the laptop seems to be a little bit warm to touch when it's plugged in and shut down. I'd think that if it's not charging beyond 60%, it shouldn't be generating any heat and should be cold.

Things I've tried:

- All firmware updates have been installed.
- Switched from Windows to Linux - capacity drain happens there too

Comment: Sounds like a faulty battery.Use your warranty.